# Scale property not being affected by transition when making class active

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a modal that is supposed to scale in and out depending on whether it has a class of 'active'. However, whenever I toggle the class on/off it either fully scales out or scales in without any transition.

### Sample:

```js
const openPopupButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-popup-target]');
const closePopupButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

openPopupButtons.forEach(button, () => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const popup = document.querySelector(button.dataset.popupTarget)
    openPopup(popup)
  })
})

closePopupButtons.forEach(button, () => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const popup = button.closest('.popup')
    closePopup(popup)
  })
})

function openPopup(popup) {
  if (popup == null) return
  popup.classList.add('active')
  overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closePopup(popup) {
  if (popup == null) return
  popup.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.75);
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  border: 10px double #fff8fb;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background-color: #fcdce9;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 80%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.popup.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.popup-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
}

.popup-header .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup-header .close-popup {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.post-it {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16;
}

.popup-footer {
  padding: .5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.create-button {
  border: 3px solid #fff8fb;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2.5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button data-popup-target="#popup" class="open-popup">Open Pop-up</button>
  <div class="popup active" id="popup">
    <header class="popup-header">
      <div class="title"> Insert Text </div>
      <button data-close-button class="close-popup"> &times; </button>
    </header>
    <div class="popup-body">
      <textarea name="post-it" id="post-it" cols="30" rows="10" class="post-it"></textarea>
    </div>
    <footer class="popup-footer">
      <button class="create-button"> Create </button>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

I am unsure whether the issue is with the classes or not. When I tried to test the animation on hover, it works.
I also tried specifying what property to transition, but it still won't work. I even tried to transition all.

Comment: Add related HTML snippet too.

Comment: Sure thing! Give me one moment

Comment: There you go! I'd appreciate any assistance!

Comment: One moment, I just realized I pasted in another version of the code. One moment while I update it pleass

Comment: Made snippet of it - so if you have JS to trigger it you can also add that...

Comment: Okay! Will do! Give me one moment

Comment: All the code is updated and it includes HTML, CSSS, and JS

Comment: Those `.forEach` calls look wrong, should be `openPopupButtons.forEach(button => {` and `closePopupButtons.forEach(button => {
` ... but that doesn't explain what you're reporting, it just means the buttons won't work.

Comment: The goal would be to have many buttons that allow to open modals with unique features. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by what I'm reporting. I'm sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Oh wow, that actually fixed it all

Comment: Good stuff! The css looks fine :-)

Comment: Thank you so very much! I would have never noticed that. Are there any resources you could share that would explain why that made a difference? Thank you so much!

Comment: Try to run your own code snippet. In the snippet there is a problem with the buttons not working, however that is not the problem you are describing. If you can make the code snippet replicate the issue at hand, it will be much easier to help you out :)

Comment: I understand what you're saying! Thanks for clearing things up. I'll make sure to use that approach from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can work with this example (uses ES6 syntax a bit)

```js
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
document.querySelectorAll('[data-popup-target]').forEach(button =>
  button.addEventListener('click', openPopup)
);

document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]').forEach(button =>
  button.addEventListener('click', closePopup)
);

function openPopup(event) {
  const popupTarget = event.target.dataset.popupTarget;
  const popup = document.querySelector(popupTarget);
  if (!popup) return;
  popup.classList.add('active');
  overlay.classList.add('active');
}

function closePopup(event) {
  const popup = event.target.closest('.popup');
  if (!popup) return;
  popup.classList.remove('active');
  overlay.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.75);
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  border: 10px double #fff8fb;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background-color: #fcdce9;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 80%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.popup.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.popup-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
}

.popup-header .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup-header .close-popup {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.post-it {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16;
}

.popup-footer {
  padding: .5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.create-button {
  border: 3px solid #fff8fb;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2.5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button data-popup-target="#popup" class="open-popup">Open Pop-up</button>
  <div class="popup active" id="popup">
    <header class="popup-header">
      <div class="title"> Insert Text </div>
      <button data-close-button class="close-popup"> &times; </button>
    </header>
    <div class="popup-body">
      <textarea name="post-it" id="post-it" cols="30" rows="10" class="post-it"></textarea>
    </div>
    <footer class="popup-footer">
      <button class="create-button"> Create </button>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```